# parsing json to myObj fails because of a missing private field

Tags: java, json, serialization, annotations, gson

I want to deserialize a json collection

`{{a:"1", b:"2"},{a:"6", b:"5"},{a:"4", b:"3"}}`

to this object:

`{public String a, public String b, private String c}.`

I'm using `Gson`

```
`mOffersList.addAll((Collection<? extends Offer>) gson.fromJson(result, collectionType));`
```

My code fails because there is no way to fill member c.

I googled and saw I can use `@expose` annotation to remove field from being serialized.

But how can I achieve the other way? Meaning, not filling redundant field in the object?

I have many members to expose and only few to hide.

Comment: what do you mean by json collection?

Comment: I convert to collection type. not one instance

Answer (score 0):

If I get your original question correctly, you have an object:

```
public class MyObject {
  public String a;
  public String b;
  private String c;

  public String toString() {
    return a + " " + b + " " + c;
  }
}
```

and a JSON in the format of:

`{a:\"1\", b:\"2\"}`

And what you want to do achieve is to deserialize the JSON into `MyObject` without C being filled:

```
String json = "{a:\"1\", b:\"2\"}";
Gson g = new Gson();
MyObject myObject = g.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
System.out.println(myObject);
```

This will print out `1 2 null`, is this what you want?

Comment: that's what I want, but it fails. It doesn't ignore the extra field.

Comment: It works for me. What version of gson are you using? Did you try my exact code?